# Print a pattern in Java

Tags: syntax

This is a working program, below code is working

Used nested for loops to create a shape pattern

```
    for (i = 1; i <= numOfshape / 2 + 1; i++) {

        for (j = i; j < numOfshape; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (k = 1; k < (i + numOfshape); k++) {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (i = numOfshape/2; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (j = numOfshape; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (k = 1; k < (i + numOfshape); k++) {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear to me how the output pattern should be constructed. What do you mean by "it should only be 5 for the whole print"? I can see 29 asterisks in the expected output.

Comment: @Madara I Think you have missed to add the details or may be you added and due to some issue which you did not notice it did not got added. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Expected output has a total of 5 lines so the first three lines will be in the first Outer for-loop and the last two lines will be in the Second Outer for-loop.

Below is the working code-

```java
for (i = 1; i <= numOfshape / 2 + 1; i++) {

            for (j = i; j < numOfshape; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (k = 1; k < (i + numOfshape); k++) {
                System.out.print("x ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (i = numOfshape/2; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (j = numOfshape; j > i; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (k = 1; k < (i + numOfshape); k++) {
                System.out.print("x ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: please accept the answer if it's correct and working.